# The space $C(0,1)$ is complemented as a subspace in some Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

We know that $c_0$ is complemented by in $X$, where $c_0\subset X$ and $X$ is separable Banach space. By the way $c_0$ is the only space with this property. Does there exist results with additional conditions on $X$, such that $C(0,1)$ complemented in $X$, where $X$ is again a separable Banach space and containing $C(0,1)$?

Comment: it should be $C[0,1]$ instead of $C(0,1)$